# $\tau(n)\phi(n)\ge n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

how to prove $\forall n \in \Bbb N$ $$\tau(n)\phi(n)\ge n$$

$\tau(n)$ is number of positive divisor of $n$

my efford: if $n=p$ is prime then $\tau(p)=2,\phi(p)=p-1,2p-2\ge p$ but how prove for composite number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it for powers of primes and the multiplicative property will give you the rest.